# Using OAuth to control access for untrusted 3rd party services to our API

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, jwt

I need to secure access to an API that will be consumed by untrusted 3rd party service. My current investigations have lead me to using `grant_type=“client_credentials”` passing in the clientId and client secret I've setup for the 3rd party within my idenity server. However this flow seems to be only for Machine to Machine (MTM) connections where the client is trusted.

I can understand why: If I use this flow, with HS256, then I can see an obvious security flaw: the JWT is signed using a shared symmetric key. This means there is nothing stopping the 3rd party generating and signing their own JWT tokens using this key and circumventing the authentication server entirely. If I use RS256 however, this flaw doesn’t exist as the untrusted party only has access to the public key, so they can’t create their own signed JWTs.

**[EDIT]:** I now know that you shouldn't validate tokens at the client as there is no need, and this means they don't need the key, so this 'flaw' is moot.

**My main question is:** Is this the correct way to go for my use case, or is there a different OAuth flow I should be using here? Everything I've read suggests that `client_credentials` grant type should only be used when the client *is* the resource owner and is trusted, and this is not my scenario - however they then state you must use Implicit or Authorisation code - which both require user involvement and are also not valid for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

So I assume that you do not want the client to manually put in any password or secret when connecting/authenticating with your service. If that's the case, then keep reading, otherwise I have misunderstood your question completely.

One thing is that your client secret, will always be at risk of being compromised. There is nothing you can do about that - it's like your user's password being compromised. It's their fault.

There are things you can do to make it more secure (though this would add some level of inconvenience to the usage of your API - but you can always add an SDK for the 3rd party to use). But first, when you say untrusted, it can mean two things:

- non-malicious and untrusted (NMU): the third party will knowingly not do anything "bad" with their access to your service. Most consumers would be here.
- malicious and untrusted (MU): the third party may do something "bad". You do not know. And if this happens, it is entirely their fault and they are to blame. Not you.

Either way, you can simply make it so that they keep using your provided secret for each API request. This is the simplest approach - but of course, increases the chances of this secret being stolen.

If you want to take it one level further, then you can use this secret to issue a long lived access token to this client. If using JWT, then the signing key can be symmetric and kept to you - since they do not need to verify the token on their side. They simply use it in each request. This has problems such has how would you or they know if this access token is stolen? Plus using long lived JWT is a bad idea in general, so I would use non-jwt tokens for this if I were you.

If you want to take it a level higher (most secure): The service authenticates itself with the secret you provided to them. Then you could issue a short lived access token and a long lived refresh token to them. They would use this access token for all normal API calls to authenticate, and when it expires, they hit a special API endpoint with the refresh token to get a new access token. Furthermore, you could change the refresh token each time they hit the refresh API - this will also allow you and them to detect token theft! (See [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.2.2.3)). If you decide this approach, then you also have to take care of a few race conditions and network failure issues as mentioned in [this blog](https://hackernoon.com/the-best-way-to-securely-manage-user-sessions-91f27eeef460). Plus, you could also go about changing the JWT signing key, since you have a refresh token to fallback on! But this would give you the most secure solution for your problem.

Note that is the third party service is likely to be of type MU, then there is nothing you can do to secure your service for them - depending on what your service does, their data and "account" would be affected..

I hope this answer helps you! Feel free to message me on Discord to chat more about this. I can be found on [this server](https://discord.gg/zVcVeev) with the username rp#5569.

Comment: Thanks Rishabh, you've confirmed what I thought was the case. One part I don't really understand is when you mention that JWTs are less secure for long lived tokens than other token types. I understand that long lived tokens are inherently insecure as they can't be revoked in the OAuth (I think?). When you mention non-jwt tokens are you referring to non-OAuth frameworks like apikeys where the resource actively validates the token with the authentication server on each request so it can be revoked instantly if needed - but which incurs a scalability downside?

Comment: ...and one more thing! Your answer mentions using refresh tokens, and I understand your rationale however for the client credentials flow this is not supposed to be used (although I'm unclear why): https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.4.3

Comment: "I understand that long lived tokens are inherently insecure as they can't be revoked in the OAuth" -> So any token can be revoked as long as you have a specific reference to them in your database. In case of JWTs (and if you do not have blacklisting), there is no specific reference as such. So they cannot be revoked.

Comment: non-jwt tokens are tokens which you also store in your DB. So yes, you would have to hit your authentication server each time they are used.. bringing down scalability. But if only refresh tokens are non-JWT, then that is OK, since you will not be calling your refresh API that often anyways.

Comment: In terms of not sending refresh tokens to client, it is true that you should not do that : the reason for that is that refresh tokens are long lived, and generally do not change. And clients are untrusted, which means high chances of a long lived token being stolen. But, if you go about changing refresh tokens on each use, this nullifies this problem, and in fact, adds more security since it also helps you in token theft detection. Answering this properly here is hard due to lack of a conversation.. So email me (rishabh@supertokens.io) or message me on discord if things don't make sense.